# Mean and variance of the number of flawed bottles among a selection of 2

Tags: probability

Questions:

> Approximately 10% of the glass bottles coming off a production line have serious flaws in the glass. If two bottles are randomly selected, find the mean and variance of the number of bottles that have serious flaws.

My approach:

Let $Y$ = random variable for the number of bottles that have serious flaws.

$y = 0$ if none of the 2 bottles have a flaw, $y = 1$ is one bottle exactly has a flaw, and $y = 2 is both bottles have a flaw.

So we now have:

> P(y = 0) = 0.9 * 0.9 = 0.81
>
> P(y = 1) = 0.9 * 0.1 = 0.9
>
> P(y = 2) = 0.1 * 0.1 = 0.1

The answer is my book states that the P(y = 0) = (0.1)^2, p(1) = 2 · 0.9 · 0.1, and finally p(2) = (0.1)^3.

Can someone please explain to me how they came up with these values.

Comment: Your probabilities don't add to $1$....for $p(1)$ you only compute the probability that the first is fine and the second is defective.

Comment: Note: I doubt your book says $p(2)=.1^3$

Comment: Even further, you do some terrible arithmetic in your shown work.  $0.1\cdot 0.1= 0.01\neq 0.1$.  Similarly $0.9\cdot 0.1 = 0.09\neq 0.9$.  Do not confuse $0.1$ for $1$.  Multiplication by $1$ will not change the number.  Multiplication by $0.1$ shifts the decimal place to the left (adding an extra zero if necessary).

Comment: Recognize the underlying probability distribution as being **binomial** $B(n=2,p=0.9)$ with $P(Y=0)=p^2, P(Y=1)=2pq$ (the "2", in particular, was lacking) and $P(Y=2)=q^2$ with $p=0.9$, $q=0.1$.

Comment: @JeanMarie Shouldn't p = 0.1?

Comment: @1290 You are right!

Answer (score 1):

E(Y)=n*p=2*0.1=0.2;

Σpy=0.2?

Var(Y)=npq=np(1-p)=0.18;

E(Y^2)-(E(Y))^2=Σp*y^2+0.2^2=0.18, hopefully.

Comment: 1) You should use Latex (MathJax) in an answer 2) I think the OP should be encouraged to practise his (maybe latent) knowledge of formula Var(Y)=npq.